# How to customize UI Patterns

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Worklight 6.0 has enhanced rich page editor with ability to create views from palette of predefined set of screens. Nice feature for repeating screens structures, I do not see however how can I add my own templates to list of patterns -- is it possible at all? Or to rephrase, is there a way, let say unsupported, to somehow extend this list manually (decompressing specific WL features/plugins of Studio and adding code snippets, image previews etc)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this in Worklight 6.0.

However, you could navigate here: your_workspace_path/.metadata/.plugins/com.ibm.etools.rpe.mobile.patterns/patterns/an_existing_pattern/your_current_framework

and modify one of the existing patterns (that you won't use at all), to fill your needs.

I insist this is basically a hack and it is totally unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out 2 things
1) We have this listed as a feature request. We can't comment on release dates, but this is a feature we would like to implement
2) I just wanted to emphasize that Orlando's response is an "unsupport solution", and may be wiped out during an upgrade. Although it may work, you would be totally on your own with this solution.

Thanks
Billy